# How to access input variables when event is fired

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapps, ethereumjs

I tried multiple methods but I still can't access the data that is passed to the event in the code. Let's say I have the following contract with an event:

`contract EtherBay {
    event NewEvent(address addr, uint intValue, bytes32 name);
    function withdraw() returns (bool) {
        NewEvent({ addr: 0, intValue: 10, name: 'someString'});
    }
 }`

Then in the js file I am using web3 to catch thrown event. Here is the code:
   `web3.eth.filter("NewEvent")
    .watch(function(error, result) {
        console.log(result)
    });`

The app enters the filer above but I am not sure of how to retrieve the data I passed when fired event (addr, intValue, name). I followed multiple tutorials online but none of them worked. I also tried to access the transaction by transactionHash but I could just retrieve intValue and name. Moreover, when I try to convert name to Ascii I get some weird characters along with the name itself. The version of solidity is 0.4.18.

Comment: Please post how you tried to access the data and how it failed

Comment: And please post the string that returns weird character when converting to Ascii

Comment: @gisdev_p Sorry, didn't think about that. I tried to access the data using getTransaction method from web3. Here is what I did: `inputHex = web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionHash).input`. As I understood input is exactly what I am looking for.  Then I tried to decode the input using web3.toAscii method: `web3.toAscii(inputHex)`. The result of the last command is equal to: '*{±àCoke\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000*'. As you can see, name=Coke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contract syntax is wrong, it shouldn't even compile.

```
contract EtherBay {
    event NewEvent(address addr, uint intValue, bytes32 name);

    function withdraw() returns (bool) {
enter preformatted text here
        NewEvent({ addr: 0, intValue: 10, name: 'someString'}); // This is incorrect.
    }
 }
```

You should be firing the event like this:

```
NewEvent(0x0...., 10, "someString");
```

Comment: I already tried that and it gives me an error if I fire the event like that.

Comment: Actually, I just tried that and it seems to be working. Not sure why I previously had an error. However, I am still having a hard time decoding the input. I also take the transactionHash, then look up this transaction and decode the input. The result is still the same: '*{±àCoke\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000*'.